# SQLITE Python cannot change value

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating an ATM program that stores all registered users in a database and starts them with $500 in cheqings.  I have created a function to deposit money but when I run it I get this error

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

```
def depositCheq(userID):

while True:

    cheqDeposit = input("How much would you like to deposit?: $")

    """try:
        c.execute('UPDATE userAccounts SET cheqBal += ? WHERE id = ?',(int(cheqDeposit)), (userID,))
        print("Deposit Complete.\n")
        break
    except:
        print("Could not deposit, error!")"""


    c.execute('SELECT cheqBal FROM userAccounts WHERE id = ?', (userID,))
    cheqBal = (c.fetchone()) + (cheqDeposit,)
    c.execute('UPDATE userAccounts SET cheqBal = ? WHERE id = ?', ([cheqBal], [userID]))
    conn.commit()
    print("Deposit Complete!\n")



def userMenu():

var = input("1: Deposit\n2: Withdrawl\n3: Check Balance\n4: Log Out\n")

if(int(var) == 1):
    userIn = input("1: Cheqings\n2: Savings\n")
    userName = input("Enter your username: ")
    if(int(userIn) == 1):
        database.depositCheq(userName)
    elif(int(userIn) == 2):
        database.depositSav(userName)
```

Comment: Why the list as `[cheqBal]` or `[userID]` in `update` query? Shouldn't it be a tuple?

Comment: The error message tells you which line the error is on. See how to create an [mcve].

Comment: @kuro that was just another suggestion from online it didn't work though.